# google spreadsheet: extract multiple numbers from text cells

Tags: excel, search, spreadsheet

I'm working on a google spreadsheet with something like this (it's a single column):

```
1
2
3,4
5
6-9
15
18
```

3,4 is 3 and 4

6-9 is 6, 7, 8 and 9

On another sheet I made a standard 1-100 list and I have to find a way to "mark" the numbers that appears or that are included on the previous list, like this.

```
1       YES
2       YES
3       YES
4       YES
5       YES
6       YES
7       YES
8       YES
9       YES
10      NO
11      NO
12      NO
13      NO
14      NO
15      YES
```

I can easily find the simple unique numbers by using in cell B1:
    =IF((COUNTIF(list!$A$1:$A$100,VALUE(A1))=1),"YES","NO")

I can even find what the first number is:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(list!$A$1:$A$100,(SEARCH(",",list!$A$1:$A$100)-1)),IFERROR(LEFT(list!$A$1:$A$100,(SEARCH("-",list!$A$1:$A$100)-1)),list!$A$1:$A$100))
```

But I can't expand the search to include the numbers between the "x-y" or after the comma in "x,y".

I've tried AND("bigger than 1st number","smaller than 2nd number") but I haven't found a way to extract the second number.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro that will work for an **excel** spreadsheet.  You can adapt it to Google apps script:

```
Sub IsItThere()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim v As Variant, i As Long, ary()
    Dim N1 As Long, N2 As Long, j As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    s1.Activate

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If InStr(1, v, ",") > 0 Then
            c.Add CLng(Split(v, ",")(0))
            c.Add CLng(Split(v, ",")(1))
        ElseIf InStr(1, v, "-") > 0 Then
            N1 = CLng(Split(v, "-")(0))
            N2 = CLng(Split(v, "-")(1))
            For j = N1 To N2
                c.Add j
            Next j
        Else
            c.Add CLng(v)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim ary(1 To c.Count)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ary(i) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    s2.Activate

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To c.Count
            If v = ary(j) Then
                Cells(i, 2).Value = "YES"
                GoTo pass
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, 2).Value = "NO"
pass:
    Next i
End Sub
```